# Question about Hilbert-Schmidt Operators

Tags: functional-analysis

[image]

I have already tried but I failed. I can't show it is. I used this way:

$| (Kf)_n |^2 \leq c_n \|f\|^2$, and therefore $\|Kf\|^2 \leq \|c\| \|f\|^2$, so that 
$\|K\| \leq \sqrt{\|c\|} $
is bounded, 
but I cant take result.

Comment: Do you know that you can think of the Hilbert-Schmidt norm as the square root of the sum of the squares of the entires of the infinite matrix representing the operator?

Comment: No i dont know is it useful

Answer (score 2):

From [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator) we know that
$$
\Vert K\Vert_{HS}^2=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\Vert K(e_i)\Vert^2
$$
Now we compute
$$
\Vert K(e_i)\Vert^2
=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|K(e_i)_n|^2
=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left|\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} k_{j+n}(e_i)_j\right|^2
=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left|\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} k_{j+n}\delta_{i,j}\right|^2
=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|k_{i+n}|^2
$$
$$
\Vert K\Vert_{HS}^2
=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\Vert K(e_i)\Vert^2
=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|k_{i+n}|^2
=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\sum_{m=i+1}^\infty|k_m|^2
=\sum_{m=1}^\infty(m-1)|k_m|^2
\leq\sum_{m=1}^\infty m c_m^2
\leq\sum_{m=1}^\infty m c_m\cdot c_m
\leq\sum_{m=1}^\infty c_m
=\Vert c\Vert_{\ell_1(\mathbb{N})}<+\infty
$$
Thus $\Vert K\Vert_{HS}\leq \Vert c\Vert_{\ell_1(\mathbb{N})}^{1/2}$, then $K$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator.